# System.InvalidOperationException error reason?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-6.0, bigbluebutton

I am using BigBlueButtonAPI.NET Package in .Net6.

in my appsetting I declared these variables:

```
"BigBlueButtonAPISettings": {
"ServerAPIUrl": "https://myserver.com/bigbluebutton/api/",
"SharedSecret": "my shared secret here"
}
```

in my program.cs I wrote these codes:

```
builder.Services.Configure<BigBlueButtonAPISettings> 
(builder.Configuration.GetSection("BigBlueButtonAPISettings"));
builder.Services.AddScoped<BigBlueButtonAPIClient>(provider =>
  {
    var settings = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<BigBlueButtonAPISettings>>().Value;
    var factory = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
    return new BigBlueButtonAPIClient(settings, factory.CreateClient());
  });
```

When I want to call an API inside my application, in program.cs I see this error:

[image]

Comment: The exception message already tells you: No service for type `IHttpClientFactory` has been registered. Where do you believe you're registering one?

Comment: (I suspect you just need to call `builder.Services.AddHttpClient()`.)

Comment: for me the error message is self explaning, you need to register the desired servese to

Comment: Please: [read the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests). Software development requires research of your own.

Comment: @JHBonarius I searched before asking the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Where exactly should I use it ?

Comment: As JHBonarious says, read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. maybe it would be helpful for others too. I added `builder.Services.AddHttpClient();` before the codes:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

builder.Services.Configure<BigBlueButtonAPISettings> 
(builder.Configuration.GetSection("BigBlueButtonAPISettings"));
builder.Services.AddScoped<BigBlueButtonAPIClient>(provider =>
{
var settings =provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<BigBlueButtonAPISettings>>().Value;
var factory = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
return new BigBlueButtonAPIClient(settings, 
factory.CreateClient());
});
```